# Create a sqlalchemy engine using an existing psycopg2 connection pool

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, connection-pooling, psycopg2

I'm adding a new ORM class using sqlalchemy's declarative mapping system. My codebase has an existing psycopg2 connection pool, which I want to reuse - I don't want code using my orm classes to have its own pool. There's a lot of existing code which directly calls `get_conn` on the psycopg2 pool, so I don't want to just replace it either.

I'm having a problem constructing the engine to connect with.

```
pool_config = {...}
POOL = psycopg2.pool.ThreadedConnectionPool(0, 32, **pool_config)

[...]

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://', pool=POOL)
Session = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
...
```

The problem is with my call to `create_engine`;

```
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 362, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 159, in create
    event.listen(pool, 'first_connect', on_connect)
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/api.py", line 63, in listen
    _event_key(target, identifier, fn).listen(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/registry.py", line 190, in listen
    dispatch_descriptor = getattr(target.dispatch, identifier)
AttributeError: 'ThreadedConnectionPool' object has no attribute 'dispatch'
```

Is it possible to use my existing pool in this way, or do I need to make a separate connection pool to be used by these classes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [custom connection function](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#using-a-custom-connection-function):

```
create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://', creator=POOL.getconn)
```