# create_engine using ssl problem sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use sqlaclhemy to create an engine using `create_engin()` method. Before the ssl I was using the command:

```
conn_string = r'postgresql://root:my_pass@hostname/db_name'
self.engine = create_engine(conn_string)
```

But after starting to use ssl this stopped working. I tried looking for similar problems and found [How do I connect to Postgresql using SSL from SqlAchemy+pg8000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095591/how-do-i-connect-to-postgresql-using-ssl-from-sqlachemypg8000)

But when I try to use the answer     `self.engine = create_engine(conn_string, connect_args={'sslmode': 'require'})` I get an error

*password authentication failed for user "root"*

Even though my password is correct. I was able to connect using *psychopg2* api as follows:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='postgres', user='root', password=my_pass,
                     host=host_name, port='5432', sslmode='require')
```

This works for me, but it is not good because I have my own api that uses sqlalchemy engine and I don't want to break it. 
I have tried to find a way to maybe create an engine using the conn created above, but the only thing I could find is [Create a sqlalchemy engine using an existing psycopg2 connection pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35089043/create-a-sqlalchemy-engine-using-an-existing-psycopg2-connection-pool), and I don't need a thread pool, nor does the psycopg2 has a .pool method anyways

How is it possible that the psycopg2 succeed where the sqlalchemy fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently the problem was with the password.
When passing connect_args argument, if you have some special characters [for me it was %] in the password, then sqlalchemy parse the string badly, thus you will get a password authentication failed for user "root" error

[for example for the following password won't work

```
kltgg2dds$fdslkj%3
```

but for a password without the % it will work]

Comment: One has to URL encode the stuff, see the answer linked as duplicate above. I always read answers before the question so I missed the linked answer above and thus I added this comment for future searchers. Take care!